# Llenar un array desde la posición con la menor sección de blancos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente array e ingreso cantidad = 1 y valor H

```
["A", "A" , "", "" , "" , "B", "", ""]
```

y el resultado deseado seria el siguiente:

```
["A", "A" ,"" , "" ,"" , "B", "H", ""]
```

Es decir mandar el valor donde haya la menor cantidad de espacios en blancos y dejar el espacio con mayor capacidad por si luego quiero ingresar una cantidad de 3 por ejemplo:

```
["A", "A" ,"J" , "J" ,"J" , "B", "H", ""]
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser un poco más claro con tu código?

Comment: ¿Qué ocurriría si en el último ejemplo en lugar de espacio=2 y valor=D hubiera sido espacio=4? ¿Cuál habría sido el resultado esperado: error o dddbbcd?

Comment: Si tendría que haber un error y me hiciste pensar otro problema que me pareció interesante :) gracias

Comment: Por favor no publiques en más de un sitio al mismo tiempo... Tu pregunta, luego de la edición, quedó poco clara. ¿Podrías editarla marcando qué es lo que estás preguntando realmente y eliminar todo lo que no sea pertinente o ya fue respondido?

Comment: @Elio ¿Y qué debería hacer si no hay espacio? Por ejemplo, si `cantidad = 3` y `arr = ["A", "", "", "B", "", ""]`

Comment: No deberia de poder llenarse, mas bien en esta parte tendria que acomodar el array y poner los espacios en blanco al final.

Comment: Hola! Gracias parece que tu solución bota el error o me equivoco?

Comment: @Elio Exacto. Puse la línea `throw new RangeError("No existen ...")` a ´propósito para que dispare el error. Se puede modificar como quieras: ya sea reacomodando los espacios, no haciendo nada, o manejando el error por fuera de la función con `try{ } catch (error) { }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de un método *mágico* para llenar la menor sección con valores vacíos consecutivos, sólo se debe recorrer el array. Cuando se encuentra una posición vacía (con `""`), seguir avanzando en el array las posiciones consecutivas que tienen vacíos, guardando en variables la posición y el tamaño de la menor sección.

El siguiente código llena la menor sección con una cantidad dada de valores (ver los comentarios):

```js
function insertarEnMenorVacio(arr, cantidad, valor) {
    var cantidad      = parseInt(cantidad, 10),
        len           = arr.length,
     lenCant       = len - cantidad + 1,
        menorEspacio  = len + 1,
        posEncontrada = -1;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < lenCant; i++) { //Recorrer el array
     if (arr[i] === "") { //Se encontró un vacío
            var espaciosDesde = i++;
            //Ver cuántos vacíos consecutivos hay
            while (i < len && arr[i] === "") { i++ }

            //Se encontró posible lugar?
            var cuantosVacios = i - espaciosDesde;
            if (cuantosVacios >= cantidad         //entra acá
              && cuantosVacios < menorEspacio) {  //es menor que el que se encontró antes
             menorEspacio  = cuantosVacios;
                posEncontrada = espaciosDesde;
                if (menorEspacio == cantidad) {
                    break; //La posición encontrada tiene los mismos espacios que cantidad
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (posEncontrada == -1)
     throw new RangeError("No existen " + cantidad + " espacios vacíos en el array.")
    //Llenar el array con el nuevo valor en la mejor posición
    arr.fill(valor, posEncontrada, posEncontrada + cantidad);
}


//Ejemplo de prueba
var arr = ["A", "A" , "", "" , "" , "B", "", "", "C", "", "", ""];

insertarEnMenorVacio(arr, 1, "H");
console.log("1, H -->", JSON.stringify(arr));

insertarEnMenorVacio(arr, 1, "I");
console.log("1, I -->", JSON.stringify(arr));

insertarEnMenorVacio(arr, 3, "X");
console.log("3, X -->", JSON.stringify(arr));

insertarEnMenorVacio(arr, 2, "más");
console.log("2, más -->", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: La solución es buena cuando se tiene un array que no esta vacio, pero cuando se envia un array de tamaño (7)  ["", "" , "", "" , "" , "", ""] e ingreso por ejemplo (3,A) Y (3,B) ->> ["A", "A" , "A", "B , "B" , "B", "B"]

Comment: fue en un error mio!!! Excelente muchas gracias

Comment: @Elio Me alegra que te haya sido útil.

Comment: Si yo llamo a la función a través de una botón enviando lo siguiente:  `insertarEnMenorVacio(arrayMemoria, cantidad, value);` y envio datos 2 veces primero 3, a y luego 3, b  se da el siguiente resultado `["a", "a", "a", "", "", "", ""] ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"]` , no esta funcionando correctamente...

Comment: @Elio Lo más probable es que estés pasando un string en vez de un número en `cantidad`. No es un error de la función. Sin embargo, edité la respuesta y agregué una línea para convertirlo en entero si se pasa como string. Verificalo y te va a funcionar incluso si pasas `cantidad` como string.

Comment: Wow... al parecer soy muy novato me podrías explicar bien sobre esto?

Comment: @Elio al pasar `cantidad` como `"3"` en vez de `3`, al sumar el valor dentro de la función, se generaba otro numero. Por ejemplo `2 + "3" == "23"`, en vez de `2 + 3 == 5` ... Para convertir de `"3"` a `3`, estoy usando `parseInt(cantidad, 10)`